# matriz nxn de números reales entre 1 y 50 con dos decimales

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

quiero crear una matriz n x n con valores reales aleatorios entre 0 y 50 (ambos inclusive) redondeado a 2 decimales, utilizando numpy.random, he puesto esto pero no es lo que quiero

```
     b=np.random.randint(0,50,size=(5,5))
     print(b)
```

Si alguien me puede echar una mano se lo agradezco

Comment: Qué sale como resultado del código que quieres y por qué no es lo que buscas? :)

Comment: Porque no están incluidos el 0 y el 50 y porque son enteros y se pide en el ejercicio que estén redondeados con dos decimales

Comment: No uses  randint y revisa la [documentación oficial](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/index.html#random-quick-start), que hay ejemplos que pueden ayudarte :)

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Números aleatorios reales incluidos el inicial y el final](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/486060/n%c3%bameros-aleatorios-reales-incluidos-el-inicial-y-el-final)