# Números aleatorios reales incluidos el inicial y el final

Tags: python-3.x, matrices, numpy

quiero crear una lista de números aleatorios de 0 a 50 (estando estos dos incluídos), redondeando a dos decimales, hasta el momento he pensado esto
b=np.random.rand(25)*50
print(b)
siendo éste el resultado

```
 [38.43370126  3.62505978  5.92928585  5.11369275  7.79297257 31.48448803
  21.98312095 37.07870493 45.49488594 30.8165787   0.29096849 37.80896891
   6.9382328  17.71482389 22.35619701 16.97937843 21.16619019 45.64570388
  15.13113917 24.88330309  8.07975946  8.59033652 11.74391437 20.56624809
  32.97843845]
```

Ahí no aparecen ni el 0 ni el 50. Redondearlo lo haría después con round. Si alguien me echa una mano se lo agradezco

Comment: Ya habías preguntado lo mismo https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/485911/matriz-nxn-de-n%c3%bameros-reales-entre-1-y-50-con-dos-decimales

Answer (score 2):

Entiendo que de 0 a 50 quiere decir en realidad desde 0.00 hasta 50.00, ya que luego dices que quieres redondear a dos decimales.

En realidad `rand()` produce números entre 0 (inclusive) y 1 (excluído), y con un número arbitrario de decimales. Aunque podrías hacer algo del estilo `rand()*50` para que el rango vaya de 0 a 50, en realidad el 50 nunca aparecería, porque el 1 nunca es un resultado de `rand()` (es decir, los resultados irán en realidad de 0.00000... hasta 49.999999...)

Conseguir incluir el 50.00 con la estrategia anterior parece complejo sin alterar la uniformidad de la distribución. Me explico. Puedes pensar en multiplicar por 51 en vez de por 50. De ese modo los resultados irían desde 0.00000... hasta 50.999999..., y luego artificialmente truncar a 50.00 los mayores de 50. Pero esto estaría aumentando ligeramente la probabilidad de obtener el 50.

Propongo otra estrategia, un poco tramposa, pero que funcionaría perfectamente para este caso. Se trata de generar **enteros** entre 0 y 5000 (ambos inclusive), y después dividir por 100 para obtener así los dos decimales que buscas.

Para obtener una distribucion de enteros entre N y M (ambos inclusive), puedes usar `np.random.randint(N, M+1)`. Hay que sumar 1 a M para que M pueda aparecer en los resultados.

Por tanto mi idea es:

```
numeros = np.random.randint(0, 5001, size=25)/100
```

Un ejemplo del resultado:

```
array([24.68, 15.66, 48.13, 38.92, 18.38, 47.76, 18.65, 38.09, 29.72,
        1.79, 48.93, 24.73, 46.11, 32.99,  5.45, 43.37, 11.81,  8.45,
        3.9 , 42.69, 32.81, 35.44, 36.07,  1.22,  1.17])
```

En cada ejecución particular de ese código sale un resultado diferente, por lo que puede que el 50.00 esté o no esté entre los resultados. Tiene una probabilidad pequeña de aparecer, ya que estamos tomando 25 números entre 5000 posibles, pero lo importante es que *tiene una probabilidad de aparecer*, y de hecho aparecerá en alguna de las ejecuciones de ese código, como se puede demostrar:

```
i = 0
while True:
  numeros = np.random.randint(1, 5001, size=25)/100
  if 50.00 in numeros:
    print(f"Encontrado en iteración {i}!")
    break
  i+=1
print(numeros)
```

---

```
Encontrado en iteración 61!
[17.31  8.3  37.41 29.43  6.63 26.05 19.51 50.   30.8  26.57  2.6   1.04
  7.39 28.1  38.15  2.81 35.21 41.34  7.73 11.54  4.08  2.13  0.44 31.53
 14.43]
```

Comment: Pero el 50.00 no está ni cercano, (antes me equivoqué era entre 0 y 50)

Comment: A ver... estás creando números aleatorios. La probabilidad de que te salga el 50.00 es una entre 5000. Tienes que generar muchos números para que en algún momento te salga. Si lo que pretendes es que siempre aparezca el 1.00 y  el 50.00 en la lista de resultados, entonces tendrías que aclarar un poco mejor tu objetivo, porque forzar a que aparezcan iría en contra de su probabilidad natural de aparecer.

Comment: He editado la respuesta (y la pregunta) para que vaya entre 0 y 50 y he aclarado un poco que el 50.00 de hecho puede aparecer entre los resultados, aunque que aparezca o no en una ejecución concreta es una cuestión de suerte.